# How to target element css using devtools information

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-select

I tried to search for this on google, but didn't find any answer. The question is: How to target elements css using the information I have from the dev tools. To be more precise I have a react component from a package

```
import Select from `react-select`
```

I use it as it is, and I want to change the styling for the options.  I tried with the id of the element from dev tools, with the css class from there, no result. How should I do this?

Comment: Quick and dirty: use Inline-Styles they take priority over all the others.  For ex <a style="color: blue" />

Comment: Are you trying to find the output of the component and style it permanently in your css or style it temporarily in your browser for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the field, then click inspect, should land exactly in the field, if you're using some library you may need to go up a little or if you can't find yet you could right click on the label and search for the field.

You could also add a data property and try to search from it.

Answer (score 0):

Just install React Chrome Developer Tool

You cant edit the props styles of components from inspecting.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2014/01/02/react-chrome-developer-tools.html